# Maximum difference between two elements

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of integers, i have to find out the maximum difference between any two elements such that larger number is appearing after the smaller number in the array.I used a simple approach and took the difference with the minimum number encountered so far by keeping the track of 2 things

1.Maximum difference

2.Minimum number visited so far.

```
    int min_element=arr[0];
    int diff=arr[1]-arr[0];
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]-min_element>diff)
            diff=arr[i]-min_element;
        if(arr[i]<min_element)
            min_element=arr[i];
    }
    return diff;
```

Is there a better approach for solving this problem?

Comment: Since you have *working* code and are just looking for feeback, you might want to consider this a question for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: What you have is fine.  You may be able to use various tricks to speed it up by a constant factor, but only by a constant factor (it trivially requires Ω(n) time, which your implementation achieves).  Unless this is a significant performance bottleneck for your program, make sure your compiler has optimization turned on and move on to the next concern.

Comment: Nitpick: you don't check that `arr[1]` is greater than `arr[0]`.  As long as the data isn't sorted in reverse (decreasing) order, it should sort itself out, but you need to think about boundary conditions (what if there are only 2 elements and they are not in increasing order?).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it stands, your algorithm is optimal, up to a constant factor.

Reading an array of `n` integers takes `Ω(n)`. Your algorithm is `O(n)`, so you're good.